# AgileCRM return "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" on every call

Tags: crm, agile-crm

From the agile CRM doc, trying a few simple curl calls like this one (anonymised):

```
 curl https://****.agilecrm.com/dev/api/contacts/*********** -H "Accept :application/xml" -v -u ********@***********:********************
```

And always same problem :

```
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Mon, 29 Feb 2016 15:10:50 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Server: Google Frontend
< Content-Length: 323
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="30,29,28,27,26,25"
<
```

Difficult to imagine any error in something that basic, but it doesn't work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When registering from mobile, you often have 1st letter to be capitalized.
Then, in the agilecrm interface/backoffice, if you do not put the same cap at same place, you can't login. But if you put cap in your email in API call, the server crashes (Internal Server Error).
So beware, expected capitalisation isn't consistent across the different AgileCRM parts.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication process at Agile CRM interface and Rest API level is same now. Now it is working with uppercase and lower case email with Rest API.

Comment: Tested again and adding CAPs doesn't crash anymore